# askdirectory() closing Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple GUI that has five Entry and "Browse" Button Widgets. The GUI itself is spawned from the button press of the root window. Upon pressing "Browse", I use `askdirectory()` to get the user to select a folder. This folder string is then updated in the corresponding Entry widget. However, after the user selects the "Open" in the `askdirectory()` GUI, the `dir_window` closes. Why is the toplevel window closing, and how do I update the Entry widget with the folder string?

```
def get_filename(widget_number, widget_list():
    filename = filedialog.askdirectory()
    widget_list[widget_number].insert(tk.END, filename)

def load_directories():
    dir_window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    dir_window.wm_title("Load Directories")
    dir_frame = tk.Frame(dir_window, height = 100, width = 100)
    dir_frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")
    dir_limit = 5
    text_widget_list = []
    for i in range(dir_limit)
        browse_button = tk.Button(dir_frame, text="Browse", 
                    command=lambda widget=i: get_filename(widget, widget_list))
        browse_text = tk.Entry(dir_frame, width = 100)
        widget_list.append(browse_text)
        browse_button.grid(row = i, column = 0,padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = "nsew")
        browse_text.grid(row = i, column = 1, padx = 10, pady = 10, sticky = "nsew")
```

[image: Browse GUI]

Comment: Could you post a minimal example?I think the problem isn't here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue. Turns out the Toplevel window isn't closing, it's just being hidden behind the master window. Setting `dir_window.transient(root)` stopped it from becoming hidden once the `askdirectory()` dialog closed.